# Play: where/how should I inject my database handler

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0

A Play project (Scala or Java, I use Scala here) created with *activator* starts with examples like:

```
class MyController @Inject() {...}
```

There are several such components that one can inject by default, e.g. `Environment`, and one of them is `Database`:

```
class MyController @Inject()(db: Database) {...}
```

It manages to read my conf and create a corresponding Database object that I can use in this controller - which I am unable to do otherwise without copying the db configuration.

But is it the right place to do so? Most of the controller will not use the database, so why not use a kind of "SqlHandler" that does all the database-related stuff. I though of something like

```
@Singleton
class SqlHandler @Inject()(db: Database) {
  def select() = {...db...}
  def insert() = {...db...}
}
```

and then call it like

```
class MyController @Inject() {
  def mySqlAction = Action {
    SqlHandler.select()
  }
}
```

Is it a good idea? Should I even use injection? And how do I use this singleton in the rest of my app then? (at the moment my `SqlHandler` is an `object` since its methods are static).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's good practice to place domain logic in other Module like Service, SqlHandler not in controller.

I place custom action with authenticate and filter, error handling and manipulating result code in Controller

You can inject SqlHanlder to Controller.

```
class MyController @Inject()(handler: SqlHandler)
```